# What does $x \in \langle0, 1\rangle$ mean?

Tags: notation

I know what $x \in \{0, 1\}$, $x \in [0, 1]$, and $x \in (0, 1)$ mean. But recently I encountered $x \in \langle0, 1\rangle$. What does it mean?

Source: [Problem 4760, *Crux Mathematicorum* 48.6, June 2022, pg 349. (PDF link via cms.math.ca)](https://cms.math.ca/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Wholeissue_48_6.pdf). Transcribed in its entirety:

> *Proposed by Goran Conar.*
>
> Let $a_i\in\left\langle0,\frac12\right\rangle$, $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i=1$. Prove that
> $$n\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n+1}}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{1-a_i}{1+a_i}}< (n+1)\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n+1}} $$

Comment: Without additional context, this is a hopelessly open-ended question. Even the notations that you mentioned have multiple meanings depending on context.

Comment: Without context, all I can do is make a wild guess.

Comment: Please provide more contexts to make your question clear.

Comment: One possibility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: I think a couple of months ago I saw a question posted wherein the OP used $\langle a,b \rangle$ - or perhaps it was $\langle a;b \rangle$? - to refer to $[a,b]$ (as in a closed interval), so perhaps that's relevant.

Comment: Edited to add source.

Comment: Most likely, this is an unusual notation for open intervals.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It's the notation that Norwegian high schoolers learn (presumably to distinguish it from coordinates; they also learn $\langle 0,\to\rangle$ for unbounded intervals, which is a convention I might actually find better than the usual, but they still learn $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}}$ for some reason, because screw consistency). I was going to suggest it myself.